PHPUnit - Error: Call to a member function addContext() on null
When I run tests in GitHub worklfow action on my Laravel project, I get this error from all PHPUnit tests:
Error: Call to a member function addContext() on null
The addContext() function is not my custom function.
I didn't changed the code, didn't changed the tests, just made some irrelevant chanes in my pull request.
Is there any idea how can I solve this issue?
Maybe is it a version mismatch or some not well-tested upgrade in PHPUnit?
I don't have any ide how to start solve it, so please help me some advice.
UPDATE
Here is a stacktrace:
) Domain\Customer\Tests\Customer\CustomerControllerRegisteredUserTest::shouldListAsAuthorizedUser
Error: Call to a member function addContext() on null

/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/inspector-apm/inspector-laravel/src/Providers/ExceptionsServiceProvider.php:56
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/inspector-apm/inspector-laravel/src/Providers/ExceptionsServiceProvider.php:24
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:458
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:286
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:266
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:248
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:189
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:109
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:106
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:432
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:102
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:71
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:255
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/symfony/deprecation-contracts/function.php:25
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:962
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/src/Domain/Product/Database/Factories/ProductFactory.php:49
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:454
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:433
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:417
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:149
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:416
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:400
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:399
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:284
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Relationship.php:59
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:360
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:240
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:359
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:155
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:358
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:346
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:240
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:333
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:291
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/src/Domain/Customer/Tests/Customer/CustomerControllerRegisteredUserTest.php:50
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/tests/Generic/ControllerAsRegisteredUser.php:40
/home/action-runner/actions-runner/_work/myproject/myproject/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:61


I am assuming it runs locally perfectly fine, right? Can you share the stacktrace? I want to see where is it coming from, like is it from Eloquent? From Session? From where?

Please check the PHPUnit, and Laravel Versions and also try to run with composer autodump.

@matiaslauriti Locally it work good. I updated the post with stacktrace.

Looks like a factory is failing, are you sure you have everything correctly set when running tests? This is the first thing /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:291, maybe you are trying to use a service or something like that? See that ProductFactory tries to use Generator from Faker, and then you have /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:255, so it is failing, but when you want to report the error using Sentry or something like that, it fails because you are missing extra data

On /tests/Generic/ControllerAsRegisteredUser.php:40, add a try catch and dd the exception, so we can see the real error
